# How to scale width on 100% heigh in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, height, scale

I'm creating a jQuery online turn page and want my turn page to scale to fit the browser window. I want to do height 100% in my css but want to maintain the correct scale on the width so cant do 100% width.

Is there a way to do 100% height while maintaining the correct width of my turn page, it will be 2 A4 pages in a spread if that helps at all, here is the code I'm using atm to set a width.

```
 $(function() {
     $('#mybook').booklet({
         width:  1000,
         height: 650
     });
 });
```

I'm using the booklet jquery plugin.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can set the height to the `$(window).height()` and then set the width to `$(this).height()*0.65` etc. to keep the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try multiplying height with width() * 0.65 to keep the aspect ratio.

```
var width = 1000,
    height = width * 0.65;
```

Comment: I decided to go with this and a combination of $('#containerDiv').width(); 
Seems to work well now. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code :

```
$('#mybook').css('width', $(window).width())
            .css('height',($(window).width()*0.65));
```

OR

```
$('#mybook').css('width', $(window).width())
            .css('height', $(window).height());
```